How can I reduce the size of YouTube Shorts on the home page to increase the number displayed?
I want to reduce the size of the YouTube Shorts listed on the homepage to increase the number displayed.
I've already reduced the size of normal videos using a userscript-based solution that works very well and was posted as an answer to How do I increase the number of videos shown on the Youtube homepage?
I'm now trying to reduce the size
of the YouTube Shorts, which seem even bigger next to the reduced size of the normal videos.
Does anyone know how to reduce the size of the YouTube Shorts listed on the home page to increase the number displayed?

Only one question per post, please.
